# Sylow subgroup of the normalizer of itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I was given a finite group $G$, with $P \leq G $, P is a p subgroup of $G$, and $P\in Syl_p(N_G(P))$. I want to show that P is a Sylow p subgp of $G$.

So I attempted a contradiction, supposing $P$ is not a Sylow p subgp of $G$, then by Sylow's 2nd thm, there exists a $P_1\in Syl_p(G)$ such that $P\leq P_1$.

From the hypothesis, I can also get that $P$ is proper subgroup of $P_1$

So am I on the right track, what should I do next?

Comment: And was the group $G$ assumed to be finite? If so, you should add this assumption.

Comment: I would like to assume so, then. Looks like it'll make thing a little bit easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1:** If $P \leq G$ is a $p$-group of order $p^\alpha$ and not a Sylow $p$-subgroup, then $P$ is contained in a $p$-group of order $p^{\alpha+1}$.

**Hint 2:** In a $p$-group, subgroups of index $p$ are normal.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to do if $P$ is the identity subgroup, so suppose that $|P| = p^{n} >1.$ Suppose (towards a contradiction) that $[G:P]$ is divisible by $p.$ Now $P$ permutes the right cosets of $P$ in $G$ via the action $Px \to Pxy$ for all $x \in G$ and $y \in P.$ 
Now the coset $P = P1_{G}$ is fixed by $P.$ Since $P$ is a non-trivial $p$-group, the number of cosets fixed by $P$ in the given action must be divisible by $p,$ as the totals number of cosets is $[G:P]$, which is divisible by $p.$ Hence $P$ must fix a coset $Px$ with $x \not \in P.$ Then $Pxy =Px$ for all $y \in P,$ so that $xPx^{-1} \leq P$, and in fact $xPx^{-1} = P,$ by order considerations. Then $x \in N_{G}(P).$ We have shown that the only cosets $Px$ which are fixed by $P$ are those with $x \in N_{G}(P),$ (and all such cosets are indeed fixed. Hence the number of fixed cosets is $[N_{G}(P):P],$ which we know is prime to $p$, a contradiction, as we have seen that the number of fixed cosets is divisible by $p.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If we put $\,|G|=p^nm\;,\;\;(m,p)=1\,$ , and assuming

$$\,|P|=p^k\;,\;k<n\;,\;\;|N_G(P)|=p^nm'\;,\;\;m=xm'\,$$

then

$$p^{n-k}m=[G:P]=[G:N_G(P)][N_G(P):P]=xm'\implies p\mid xm'$$

and this is a contradiction (why?)

Comment: what is $x$, just some integer?

Comment: Why can you assume that $|N_G(P)| = p^nm'$ ? I would rather say $|N_G(P)| = p^lm'$ with $l \leq n$ and $m' | m$. Do I miss something ? And indeed $l \geq k$ because $P \leq N_G(P)$.

Comment: That, and how does $[G:N_G(P)][N_G(P):P]=xm'$ follow from the assumption $p^n|\#N_G(P)$? Indeed $[G:N]$ would be $x=m/m'$, but $[N_G(P):P]$ shouldn't be $m'$, it should be $p^nm'/p^k=p^{n-k}m'$, in which case we have $p^{n-k}m=(m/m')(p^nm'/p^k)$, which doesn't get us anywhere. Another reason the argument is noticeably suspect is that the definition of $N_G(P)$ is nowhere used: we might as well be arguing that if $P$ is a non-Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$ then the existence of an intermediate-lying group $P<N\le G$ called $N$ (with maximal $p$-adic valuation) yields a contradiction.